# Let $C=C_G(H)$, $\mathfrak{c} \subseteq \mathfrak{c}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})$

Tags: algebraic-groups

> Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of the algebraic group $G$, $C=C_G(H)$. Prove that  $\mathfrak{c} \subseteq \mathfrak{c}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})=\{ \mathbb{x} \in \mathfrak{g} : [\mathbb{x}, \mathfrak{h}] =0\}$.

Here, $\mathfrak{g}$,$\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ are the Lieg algebras of $G$, $H$ and $C$ respectively.

If $I$ is the ideal of $K[G]$ vanishing on $H$, then $\mathfrak{h}$ is the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ consists of elements mapping $I$ to $0$. But what is the connection between the ideals vanishing on $H$ and $C$ making the relation $\mathfrak{c} \subseteq \mathfrak{c}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{h})$ hold? Or is there another way to prove this proposition? Many thanks.

Comment: If you go to Milne's notes on Algebraic Groups, see Prop 2.23 on pg 261.  See http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ala.html

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you very much.